# Creating Array of Specific Element From a Multi Level Array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have stored a value in a variable and value is a multi level array. and now i want to create a new array of an element from that multi level array.

Multi Level Array is

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [file_name] => 2414_Stomach.jpg [file_type] => image/jpeg [file_path] => C:/xampp/htdocs/mobile/uploads/tmp_files/ [full_path] => C:/xampp/htdocs/mobile/uploads/tmp_files/2414_Stomach.jpg [raw_name] => 2414_Stomach [orig_name] => 2414_Stomach.jpg [client_name] => 2414_Stomach.jpg [file_ext] => .jpg [file_size] => 465.53 [is_image] => 1 [image_width] => 1122 [image_height] => 741 [image_type] => jpeg [image_size_str] => width="1122" height="741" ) [1] => Array ( [file_name] => 907302_556430127722057_954171705_n.jpg [file_type] => image/jpeg [file_path] => C:/xampp/htdocs/mobile/uploads/tmp_files/ [full_path] => C:/xampp/htdocs/mobile/uploads/tmp_files/907302_556430127722057_954171705_n.jpg [raw_name] => 907302_556430127722057_954171705_n [orig_name] => 907302_556430127722057_954171705_n.jpg [client_name] => 907302_556430127722057_954171705_n.jpg [file_ext] => .jpg [file_size] => 132.98 [is_image] => 1 [image_width] => 674 [image_height] => 960 [image_type] => jpeg [image_size_str] => width="674" height="960" ) [2] => Array ( [file_name] => 1554470_695025487195853_1418731925_n.jpg [file_type] => image/jpeg [file_path] => C:/xampp/htdocs/mobile/uploads/tmp_files/ [full_path] => C:/xampp/htdocs/mobile/uploads/tmp_files/1554470_695025487195853_1418731925_n.jpg [raw_name] => 1554470_695025487195853_1418731925_n [orig_name] => 1554470_695025487195853_1418731925_n.jpg [client_name] => 1554470_695025487195853_1418731925_n.jpg [file_ext] => .jpg [file_size] => 7.39 [is_image] => 1 [image_width] => 200 [image_height] => 200 [image_type] => jpeg [image_size_str] => width="200" height="200" ) )
```

Now i want an array of all [file_name] elements.

Comment: And your question is? Just loop over the array and push the `file_name` to a new array?

Comment: Could you reformat the array so we can see the nesting structure? Use: `echo '<pre>'; var_dump($array);`

Comment: kingkero. if i knew that why i have to post here ?

Barmar : I got solution from posted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$new_array = array_map(function($a) { return $a['file_name']; }, $array);
```